# Make your own filter for PrimeNG Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

Primefaces PrimeNG has his own built in filter function like this

```
<p-column field="id" header="ID" [filter]="true"></p-column>
```

I want to call my own filter function that I have written in a component.

How can I use it in PrimeNG ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use ng-template for filter and then you can call your own function on input change.

```html
<p-column field="ColumnName" header="ColumnName" [filter]="true"                                             filterMatchMode="contains" [sortable]="true">
<ng-template let-col pTemplate="header">
   <span [pTooltip]="'ColumnName'" tooltipPosition="bottom" appendTo="body">
   ColumnName 
   </span>
</ng-template>
<ng-template let-col pTemplate="filter">
   <div class="txt-search-input-table" *ngIf="localSearch">
      <input id="txtColumnName" type="text" #txtColumnName (keyup)="YourOwnFunction(txtColumnName.value)" styleClass="ui-column-filter"
      class="form-control pull-left ipt-width-slam" name=""/>
   </div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template let-col let-row="rowData" pTemplate="body">
   <span appendTo="body" style="position: relative;">                     
   {{row[col.field]}}
   </span>
</ng-template>
</p-column>
```

Answer (score -1):

I am thinking using callback, where you pass a callback function in onFocus event:

onFocus event: Browser event    Callback to invoke when dropdown gets focus.